# Laravel Hash::make() response is different than the original hash

Tags: laravel

I'm using Hash::make to hash the customer id in my laravel api controller. But when I return the Hashed customer id I get wrong characters. Here is my code:

```
$key=Hash::make($input['key']);
$createnewkey=DB::table('customers')->where('custid', $input['custid'])
                           ->update(array("key"=>$key));
return ["STATUS"=>1, "KEY"->$key];
```

I got for example : Av$@wqe@!3aferty10/2YyAU ....  and that's saved in the database.

But the request response is :  Av$@wqe@!3aferty10/\2YyAU  the \ or / is always replaced with /\ that will corrupt my hash code compare

Answer (score 1):

Laravel `Hash` use the `password_hash` function of the `PHP`. This function will generate the **base64** encoded string. Which has the `/` in its character list. So if you will pass that in the URL your URL will get corrupted.

Instead, you can use `hashids` to encrypt the keys which are passed in URls.

This is the `hashids` port for laravel : https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids